# How does one sum only those rows in excel not filtered out?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use the `SUM(B1..B20)` formula to sum a column, but when I filter the data by an adjacent column, the sum doesn't update to reflect only those rows not filtered out.  How does one do this?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to use the **[SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939)** function.
The **SUBTOTAL** function ignores rows that have been excluded by a filter.

The formula would look like this:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,B1:B20)
```

The function number **9**, tells it to use the **SUM** function on the data range **B1:B20**.

If you are '*filtering*' by hiding rows, the function number should be updated to **109**.

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,B1:B20)
```

The function number **109** is for the **SUM** function as well, but hidden rows are ignored.

Comment: Function number 109. Well, that would be easy to guess now wouldn't it...

Thanks for this: I've been using Excel for years but hadn't come across this one.

Comment: The various SUBTOTAL functions are fully documented in the Help, both  inbuilt and online...

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't using an auto-filter (i.e. you have manually hidden rows), you will need to use the [`AGGREGATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) function instead of `SUBTOTAL`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use autofilter to filter results, Excel doesn't even bother to hide them: it just sets the height of the row to zero (up to 2003 at least, not sure on 2007).

So the following custom function should give you a starter to do what you want (tested with integers, haven't played with anything else):

```
Function SumVis(r As Range)
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim total As Variant

    For Each cell In r.Cells
        If cell.Height <> 0 Then
            total = total + cell.Value
        End If
    Next

    SumVis = total
End Function
```

Edit:

You'll need to create a module in the workbook to put the function in, then you can just call it on your sheet like any other function (=SumVis(A1:A14)). If you need help setting up the module, let me know.